# CSS Div overlapping

Tags: css

I'm confused in some CSS trick. The scenario is painted below. In the 2nd container is a plugin like http://workshop.rs/projects/coin-slider/

I want to move that 2nd container up (the green one), to be connected with the menu bar. The purpose is, I want the Image Logo overlaping the 2nd container. How can I achieve that ?
I tried simply set the negative value of the `margin-top` property of the 2nd container but it causes that the div's are moved.

[image: .]

Comment: `Position: relative;` and a negative `top` value should do it.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
#container-2 {
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  top:-0px /* <-- Put actual value here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you could post you css code.

Somes possibilites:
set  "image logo" `margin-bottom` to a negative value and make sure container#1 `height` isn´t preventing the bottom container go up.

or set both containers `position: absolute` and then set property `top` to match the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a `position: absolute` for the image logo.